# Unable to find an entry point named 'NetSecurityNative_ImportPrincipalName' in shared library 'System.Net.Security.Native'

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core

I am running sql server on Mac using docker and it is talking to my .net core application. I am running specflow tests which connects to the specified database, creates the required schema and then run the tests. I get the following exception when I run these tests on Mac but it works fine on a windows machine. Are there any libraries missing in .net core?

My connection string looks like this: public static string ConnectionString = @"Server=localhost:1433; Database=csn_product; User=sa; Password=****;";

```
MultipleActiveResultSets = true; Trusted_Connection=False; Integrated_Security=False
```

I have also tried the above parameters in connection string but nothing worked.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException: Failed to connect to server MyServer. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Unable to find an entry point named 'NetSecurityNative_ImportPrincipalName' in shared library 'System.Net.Security.Native'.
   at Interop.NetSecurityNative.ImportPrincipalName(Status& minorStatus, String inputName, Int32 inputNameByteCount, SafeGssNameHandle& outputName)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle.CreatePrincipal(String name)
   at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteNegoContext..ctor(SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, String targetName)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.EstablishSecurityContext(SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, String targetName, ContextFlagsPal inFlags, SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, ContextFlagsPal& outFlags)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.InitializeSecurityContext(SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, SafeDeleteContext& securityContext, String spn, ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, SecurityBuffer[] inSecurityBufferArray, SecurityBuffer outSecurityBuffer, ContextFlagsPal& contextFlags)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GenSspiClientContext(SspiClientContextStatus sspiClientContextStatus, Byte[] receivedBuff, Byte[]& sendBuff, Byte[] serverName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.GenerateSspiClientContext(Byte[] receivedBuff, UInt32 receivedLength, Byte[]& sendBuff, UInt32& sendLength, Byte[] _sniSpnBuffer)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SNISSPIData(Byte[] receivedBuff, UInt32 receivedLength, Byte[]& sendBuff, UInt32& sendLength)
  at at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
  at at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
  at at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
  at at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
  at at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
  at at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
  at at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
  at at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.InternalConnect()
  at at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()
```